# finding limit for a two variable function

Tags: limits, functions, maxima-minima

How can I calculate 
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,-1)}  \frac{x+y}{1+xy}$$

I want to show that this function has a maximum value of 1. I found the maxima are at (±1,±1) and for$ (1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ , $f(x,y)= 1$ . I am stuck on the rest two.$$$$
Edit: I will explain a little more about the situation, in special relativity, velocity addition has the form $$ \overline{v} = \frac{w+V}{1+\frac{wV}{c^2}} $$
 where velocities have usual meanings. So, when a frame is moving away from you with a speed of $c$ and light flashes towards you in the opposite direction, you should get $$ \overline{v} = -c $$ because the speed of light is same in all the frame of references.  How can we justify that from this equation? Essentially I have to prove that $ \overline{v}$ never exceeds $c$

Comment: This function is clearly unbounded because we can just let $y\to -1/x$ for any constant $x\ne\pm1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that for $x=1+t$ and $y=-1+t$ with $t\to 0$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,-1)}  \frac{x+y}{1+xy}=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2t}{t^2}=0=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2}{t}=\pm\infty$$

---

*Added after editing*

For the problem you are referring to the limit to look should be

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1^-,-1^+)}  \frac{x+y}{1+xy}$$

since we are assuming $-1<x,y<1$.

More in general we are interested to bound the given function when $-1<x,y<1$, then we can let

- $x=\tanh u \in(-1,1)\quad u\in \mathbb R$
- $y=\tanh v \in(-1,1)\quad v\in \mathbb R$

and therefore by the [sum identity for $\tanh$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Sums_of_arguments)

$$\frac{x+y}{1+xy}=\frac{\tanh u+\tanh v}{1+\tanh u \tanh v}=\tanh (u+v)$$

which leads to

$$-1<\frac{x+y}{1+xy}<1$$

Comment: so limit does not exist since left and right side limits are not equal?

Comment: @annoying_noob Yes exactly. For some trajectory $f\to \infty$ and for others $f\to -\infty$. Therefore $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: Then how can I proceed in the above-mentioned situation?

Comment: @annoying_noob We can conclude that the limit doesn't exist and that $f(x,y)$ has not min/max.

Comment: I meant how can we recover $$\overline{v} = c$$ from the relativistic addition of velocities mentioned in the question

Comment: @annoying_noob Ah ok! I'll take a look to that.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: @annoying_noob You are welcome! Bye